# web-page field for j2me blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, java-me, webbrowser-control

Can I integrate a standard BlackBerry web-browser in my BlackBerry application? Similar to embedding Internet Explorer in a standalone desktop application on C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html), which lets you embed a browser within your java-me app.